meaning of the sentence in bold is uncler to me
As he walked through the dark night he was overwhelmed by an urge to
escape from his present mental state. Thoroughly weak, agitated, unstable,
anxious; seriously wanting in courage and bereft of any largeness of spirit
—this was how he came to see himself. Oppressed by something that
weighed down heavily on his breast, all he could think about was what
practical course he might adopt that would deliver him from his current
predicament, the causes of which—his own sins of commission and
omission—were at the moment quite detached in his mind from the delayed
effect they had produced. For now he had no capacity to think about others,
consumed as he was by concern for himself alone.
Does it mean: He wanted to get rid of somethings that made him to select wrong way that now he suffer from their delayed effect?
I really do not get its meaning clearly Could you write it in other words?
Source: The Gate by NATSUME SŌSEKI Translated by WILLIAM F. SIBLEY

"Sins of commission and omission" are things you did that you should not have done and things you failed to do that you ought to have done.
The character's past sins have caused his current predicament, but at the moment he is unable to think about them, only about the effect they have had (his predicament, whatever that is).

Maybe- it could also mean that he is unable to make the connection between the sins and the effects, or that there is actually no connection. It’s a nice turn of phrase, capable of several interpretations.
